# Indenting here doc

Tags: bash, heredoc

I have a function to install jackett, the function contains the heredoc that writes a service file.

The problem is i need to indent the EOF but it wont work, i have tried multiple itterations of code and examples none seem to work.

i have tried the below both with and without "",'',- around EOF

```
cat <<-EOF > /etc/systemd/system/jackett.service
EOF

cat > /etc/systemd/system/jackett.service <<-EOF
EOF

cat <<-EOF
EOF > /etc/systemd/system/jackett.service
```

This is the actual code i have written.

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev bzip2 mono-devel -y

cd /tmp

wget https://github.com/Jackett/Jackett/releases/download/v0.8.832/Jackett.Binaries.Mono.tar.gz

sudo tar -xvf Jackett*

sudo mv Jackett/* /opt/jackett

sudo chown -R plex-admin:plex-admin /opt/jackett

cat <<-EOF > /etc/systemd/system/jackett.service
    [Unit]
    Description=Jackett Daemon
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=$Admin
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=5
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart
    TimeoutStopSec=20

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

sudo systemctl enable jackett

sudo service jackett start
```

Please help.

**Edit 1**

As per the comment by Charles Duffy

my test file is

```
#!/bin/bash

cat -A  <<-EOF
    [Unit]
    Description=Jackett Daemon
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=$Admin
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=5
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart
    TimeoutStopSec=20

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

The output when running the bash script is

```
    [Unit]$
    Description=Jackett Daemon$
    After=network.target$
$
    [Service]$
    User=$
    Restart=always$
    RestartSec=5$
    Type=simple$
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart$
    TimeoutStopSec=20$
$
    [Install]$
    WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

**Edit 2**

So atom has a cool feature called 'convert all spaces to tabs' i selected my cat function now the out put with -A is below.

```
[Unit]$
Description=Jackett Daemon$
After=network.target$
$
[Service]$
User=$
Restart=always$
RestartSec=5$
Type=simple$
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart$
TimeoutStopSec=20$
$
[Install]$
WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

and it works!

Comment: The kind of whitespace in use is critical. `<<-EOF` only works if your editor uses tabs, not spaces.

Comment: Im using nano if thats a problem?

Comment: That you're using nano doesn't really tell us anything either way about the whitespace type. If you're on a system with GNU `cat`, does `cat -A <yourfile` show spaces for the leading space, or does it show them as `^I` sequences?

Comment: BTW, I'd strongly creating a new temporary directory (as with `tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/jackett-installer.XXXXXX)`) for your code to run in. Assuming that `/tmp/Jackett*` won't match anything but your unpacked tarball isn't necessarily well-founded.

Comment: the jacket install script is part of a bigger setup script what is the benefit of the temp directory?

Comment: Your output confirms that your script is indenting the here document with spaces, not tabs, as `-`-prefixed delimiters require.

Comment: so i am using nano on my linux machine if that changes anything, what is the best way to get around it?

Comment: When using `<<-EOF`, you can add indentation with spaces, **but the last line, containing `EOF`, must use tabs**.

Comment: @Pawamoy You can use spaces, but they won't be stripped like leading tabs will be, although you are correct about the delimiter needing tabs only before it.

Comment: @RhysClarke, the point of the temporary directory is it's guaranteed to have no contents unrelated to your script, so your globs will never expand to anything you don't expect them to. Using a shared directory that every user/account on your system can write to is asking from trouble, both accidental or malicious (if an unprivileged account like `nobody` is broken into -- and such accounts are often used for sandboxing untrusted code, so this is not unheard of -- it can still write to `/tmp`, and so can create files or directories that the glob `/tmp/Jackett*` will match).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected my cat statement in atom and went to; Packages > Whitespace > Convert Spaces To Tabs.

cat function output with -A is below.

```
[Unit]$
Description=Jackett Daemon$
After=network.target$
$
[Service]$
User=$
Restart=always$
RestartSec=5$
Type=simple$
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart$
TimeoutStopSec=20$
$
[Install]$
WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

and it works!